# dask cluster doesn't utilise all cores

Tags: dask, dask-distributed

I tried to use `dask_jobqueue` to initiate a cluster and successfully launched many running jobs and cores (more than the desired number of workers; e.g., 100 cores were successfully acquired from the cluster); however, in the cluster widget, I noticed only part of the jobs were associated with the `Dask.cluster` as workers (e.g., 20).

What is the reason for that? how to debug?

And I still don't understand how the number of workers are determined by the `dask_jobqueue.cluster`. Shouldn't it be the same as the number of cores acquired from the cluster?